# Improve the smoothness of a basic WPF storyboard animation

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I've been playing around with some basic WPF Storyboard animation and it looks quite blurry, it's Ok up to a certain speed then really degrades into blurryness.

Is there anyway I can get it to look smoother? - increase the framerate somehow or maybe double buffer the animation?

I've tried setting the objects to CacheMode="BitmapCache" but this seems to have little effect.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Width="1000" Height="600" >
        <Window.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded" >
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="600" To="-600" Duration="00:00:02" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MyObject" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Window.Triggers>

        <Grid>
            <Grid Name="MyObject">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>

                <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Fill="Green" StrokeThickness="3" Width="100" Height="250" />
                <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="3" Width="80" Height="180" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try increasing the `FrameRate`:

```
MediaTimeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(System.Windows.Media.Animation.Timeline), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(60));
```

The higher the number, the higher the framerate (the smoother the execution). Be cautious though, higher framerates impact performance!

I hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem - but I think I'm just expecting too much from WPF!

Comment: Sometimes increasing the FrameRate will have a reverse impact too...if the demands on the rendering system exceed the performance threshold. I generally set my animation FrameRate to about 10 and it is sufficient. You can always increase it until it looks the way you want.

I would try setting that value to 10 and see if it makes any difference at all.

Comment: Don't lower your expectations too far....I myself have done some pretty incredible things within the WPF space, and others have blown the doors off. Keep thinking big...it may not always work the way you think it should, but WPF is a pretty powerful framework. Stick with it!