# WPF Storyboard animation unintended shaking

Tags: wpf, animation, checkbox, storyboard

I'm trying to create an animated checkbox in WPF, similar to [this one](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/animated-material-design-checkbox-with-css-css3/).

This question is NOT a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565368/improve-the-smoothness-of-a-basic-wpf-storyboard-animation), because there is no problem with the framerate of the animation.

The animations and the storyboards are already in place, and working properly, but for some rason, while the animation is playing, it looks like the whole thing is shaking, as demonstrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66UST.jpg). The effect is best seen on the right border of the box.

The following is the XAML source code of the custom checkbox. I don't think that there is a need to post the code behind, since it doesn't contain anything other than the RoutedEvent definitions (`FlatCheckBox.Checked` and `FlatCheckBox.Unchecked`).

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="Sync_Launcher.Controls.FlatCheckBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Sync_Launcher.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30"
         Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="FlatCheckBox_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=userControl}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Column="0">
        <Grid Name="tickHolderGridRoot" Margin="4">
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotationTransform" Angle="0"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Grid Name="tickHolderGrid" Margin="0,0">
                <Border Name="tickBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Opacity="0" BorderThickness="2,0,0,2" BorderBrush="#FF1CA36F" />
                <Border Name="overlayBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Opacity="1" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="#FF404D61" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Label 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=userControl}" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
        FontSize="16" 
        Padding="5,0" 
        FontStyle="{Binding FontStyle, ElementName=userControl}" 
        FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</Grid>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Duration x:Key="animationDuration">0:0:0.4</Duration>
    <KeyTime x:Key="animationEnd">0:0:0.4</KeyTime>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="userControl" RoutedEvent="controls:FlatCheckBox.Checked">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="60">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="rotationTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="{StaticResource animationEnd}" Value="-60">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="overlayBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tickBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}"/>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tickHolderGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0,0" To="0,2" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}"/>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tickHolderGridRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="4" To="2,0,2,4" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="userControl" RoutedEvent="controls:FlatCheckBox.Unchecked">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="rotationTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-60"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="{StaticResource animationEnd}" Value="0">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="overlayBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tickBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}"/>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tickHolderGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0,2" To="0,0" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}"/>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tickHolderGridRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="2" To="4" Duration="{StaticResource animationDuration}"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

I have tried increasing the storyboard framerate by settings the `Timeline.DesiredFrameRate` to 60, as you can see in the code, but it had no effect on the shakyness of the animation.

I have also tried setting the `SnapsToDevicePixels` property to `true` hoping that it would improve the animation.

What might be the cause of this shaking effect, what can I do to eliminate it?

Comment: Sweet animation. For what it's worth I tested your xaml on my windows 10 machine and the animation is completely smooth with no shaking as you demonstrated. Have you tried hosting the usercontrol in an empty application and testing it to see if the fact that your checkbox is in another container is affecting it?

Comment: Hrm.. interesting. This is on of the things I didn't try. When I made a new empty window to test it, it was perfectly smooth. It seems like the control's size affects the animation. Originally (on the gif), the control was very small, but now that I mad it a bit bigger, (+4 pixels high) the animation is a lot smoother.